# How to add a class to `li` element based on a text inside using jQuery

Tags: jquery

`var id` value changes dynamically. 
How can I add `class='current'` to the list with the same text. For example when `id=1`,

```
<li class="current"><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index">1</a></li>
```

I tried this but not working.

```
<ul class='pagination'>
<li>&lt;</li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index">1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index/2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index/3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index/2">&gt;</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    var id = 1;
    $('.pagination ul li').each(function(){
        if($this.val() == id)
        {
            $this.addClass("current");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: *...to the list with the same text.* Please clarify.

Comment: val is not correct. You're looking for innerHTML. JQUERY MANUAL : 'The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty collection, it returns undefined.'

Comment: In the JQuery world, try 'text' instead of val. Also, it's $(this), not $this.

Comment: Last thing : you forgot your link. Try $('.pagination ul li a').

Comment: @shin You can check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the following three issues

1. You had the selector as `$('.pagination ul li')` which is wrong and
   it should be either `$('.pagination li')` or `$('ul.pagination li')`
2. And you used `$this` instead of `$(this)` in two places
3. Then to compare the value, you should use `$(this).find('a').text()`
   instead of `$this.val()` since you need to find the text inside the
   `anchor` tag

Working sample

```css
.current {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='pagination'>
<li></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index">1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index/2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index/3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost/myweb/index.php/blog/index/4">4</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    var id = 1;
    $('ul.pagination li').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('a').text() == id)
        {
            $(this).addClass("current");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```